# Only part of the Button Area is clickable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar with two buttons, this buttons should always be visible. So I could not use the navbar-collapse class.
With the actual styling only parts of the button area are clickable.

How can I get the same design with better button behaviour (Full Area of the button should be clickable)?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button onclick="alert('Left')" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>

        </button>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-text-extension" href="#">Date</p>
        <button onclick="alert('Right')" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>

        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeuschn/6jeyc7tk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the `navbar-text-extension` overlapping the buttons.

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jeyc7tk/4/)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button onclick="alert('Left')" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-left">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
            </button>
            <span class="navbar-text display-ib" href="#">Date</span>
            <button onclick="alert('Right')" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-text.display-ib{
    display:inline-block;
    float:none !important;
}
```

***NOTE** I removed the class that fixes the navbar to the top only for the fiddle (it should be fine with it added back in), since the fiddle window has a 'result' tag that was overlapping the button, which would make it seem as though the button still did not work.

Comment: I think this isn't quite correct; *"Date"* isn't centered anymore, unless you make the screen smaller.

Comment: Awesome. I only caught it cause I got stuck there when trying to answer this :P Cheers!